# Duplicating gtk treeviews

Tags: gtk, vala

how can I use views from .ui file many times?

I load them this way

```
var view_orig = builder.get_object("items_view") as Gtk.TreeView;
var store_orig = builder.get_object("items_store") as Gtk.TreeStore;
```

but I need create 10 copies of `view_orig`.

I write it in Vala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually wouldn't use a ui file as a template (in the sense of duplication). The only method I know is to traverse the Gtk object tree and duplicate each object you come across. Depending on how complex your tree is you might be able to get away with just looking through and duplicating the classes without any data.

I know of no convenience functions for helping you do this. And a gnome developer would probably tell you to create a factory class to build the ui or load the ui file multiple times (I believe the builder creates a new tree on each load)